# Apex heap size too large - For a web service call

Tags: apex, webservices, heapsizelimit

I know that this error is very common when the heap size is more than 12MB for an Asynchronous call, in my case, web service call out. I have referred this documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321537&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1 already, which only provides solution while we are having heap size larger at our implementation.

But, in my case, the response I have received via a web service call out is exceeding the heap size limitation and causing the exception. Is there a way/solution for this scenario? My search on the same was no fruitful, so looking for some guidance.

```
public String rawXMLResponse;
..
..
rawXMLResponse = resp.getbody(); //This is where I am getting the heap limit exception.
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no tricks I know of to help deal with this. Callouts that return too much data just simply can't be handled natively in Apex.

Realistically, the response can't be greater than 3 MB for synchronous transactions or 6 MB for an async transaction (unless you're not using the response body and just looking at the response code, for example) because we need *at least* 2x the response size in heap space.

- The response body itself consumes X heap space
- Storing the response in a new string or processing the response (say, deserializing a JSON response) requires at least X heap space (again)

And that's just to get the data into a workable state. If you want to create or manipulate records based on that data, you'll need even more heap space.

Regex can't really help, because [matcher strings are limited to 1 million characters](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325937&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

You can take substrings, but I don't know if any of the other string methods work with strings of that magnitude.

Your best bet here is to take the callout, and introduce a middle man.

- Apex would make a callout to this intermediary server
- The intermediary server would forward (or otherwise perform) the callout
- The intermediary server would capture and process the result
- The intermediary server would then pass more reasonably sized data back to Salesforce (perhaps in the same transaction, perhaps in separate transactions)